# How to pass the argument in expect shell script during runtime

Tags: shell, expect

I am trying to pass the password dynamically, while running the expect script.

Script looks somewhat like this :

```
#!/usr/bin/Expect

set server [lindex $argv 0] 

send "enter you password" 

read Password; 

send $password\n; 

spawn ssh c1210427@$server ...
```

Got stuck while getting the password from terminal during the running script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[read]` command reads until end of file so it's waiting for you to close the terminal. Use the `[gets]` command instead:

```
set password [gets stdin]
```

Also, you're using `[read]` wrong. The first argument is the channel id to read from. See the documentation for more info:

http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/read.htm

http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/gets.htm

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you have used the following code like a `puts` statement

```
send "enter your password"
```

which is not a proper way. Usually, `send` command will try to send commands to the console and if any process spawned via script, then this command will be sent to that process.

Anyway, you will get the statements get printed in the console. But, be aware of it. Instead, better use `send_user` command.

You can try out this

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set server [lindex $argv 0]

stty -echo; #Disable echo. To avoid the password to get printed in the terminal

send_user "enter you password : "

# Using regex to grab all the input till user press 'Enter'
# Each submatch will be saved in the the expect_out buffer with the index of 'n,string' 
# for the 'n'th submatch string

# expect_out(0,string) will have the whole expect match string including the newline

# The first submatch is nothing but the whole text without newline
# which is saved in the variable 'expect_out(1,string)
expect_user -re "(.*)\n" ;     

stty echo; #Enable echo

set pwd  $expect_out(1,string)

send $pwd\n;

expect "some-other-statment"

#Your further code here
```

You can remove the `stty -echo` and `stty echo` if you don't bother about the password getting printed in console

Reference : http://www.tcl.tk/man/expect5.31/expect.1.html

Comment: Hi Dinesh, my intention was to get the information dynamically from the user. Your code works fine and is more secure . But will refer the other as correct since it meets my condition exactly. Thanks for you help ... :)

Comment: Thanks Dinesh for your response. It helped me a lot